# Find all occurances of a same values

Tags: mysql

Hello and thank you in advance,

So I have a table lets call it *userrating* and inside this table I have some fields, one of which is called *userid*.

Below I will demonstrate to you how my table looks like.

```
userid  |  rating1  |  rating2 |  rating3  |  rating4 | rating5
-----------------------------------------------------------
100     |    1      |    0     |    0      |    0     |    0
101     |    0      |    0     |    1      |    0     |    0
101     |    0      |    0     |    0      |    0     |    1
112     |    0      |    1     |    0      |    0     |    0
100     |    0      |    0     |    0      |    1     |    0
101     |    1      |    0     |    0      |    0     |    0
```

What I want to do is get all the rows for the same userid's.

I want to get the 2 occurances for 100, 3 occurances for 101 and 1 occurance for 112.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What I want to do eventually, is count how many rating1, rating2, rating3 etc each user has.
So I want to have ( finally ) something like 
userid : 100 
rating1 : 1
rating2 : 0
so on and so forth.

Comment: A quick google brought your answer: http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp

Comment: I did a few google searches but I guess I was looking for the wrong thing. I will give it a try right now. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: instead of adding your expected results on comments, please edit your question so others can get idea without going through comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(rating1),SUM(rating2),SUM(rating3),SUM(rating4),SUM(rating5) 
From userrating Group By UserID
```

Also check it yourself here on fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/598b9/3